# PDF-viewer problems

Tags: ios, iphone, class, interface, root

I was following a tutorial, because i need to view pdf-documents in my app.
Link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtKoddECri0
After i made the tableview, and tried to create the .m and .h, nothing was shoving in the document, so i wrote it myself and got the following errors.
**Hold3januar.m**

```
#import "Hold3januar.h"

@interface Hold3januar ()

@end
```

**Cannot find interface declaration for 'Hold3januar'**

```
@implementation Hold3januar
```

**Cannot find interface declaration for 'Hold3januar'**

```
- (id)initWithNibName   (NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:NSbundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

**Expected method body**

```
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
```

**'Hold3januar' cannot use 'super' because it is a root class**

```
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

**'Hold3januar' cannot use 'super' because it is a root class**

```
- (void)didRecieveMemoryWarning];
```

**Expected method body**

```
{
```

**Expected identifier or '('**

```
 [super didRecieveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any ressources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```